# Is there an action functional for the s-dependent Floer equation?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

The usual Floer equation (in local coordinates)
\begin{equation*}
\partial_su+J(t,u)(\partial_tu-X_{H_t}(u))=0
\end{equation*}
is derived as the gradient flow of the symplectic action functional $\mathcal{A}_H$ and therefore its solutions connect critical points of $\mathcal{A}_H$. Is there an action functional that in the same way gives rise to the s-dependent Floer equation
\begin{equation*}
\partial_su+X_{G_{t,s}}(u)+J(s,t,u)(\partial_tu-X_{H_{t,s}}(u))=0 
\end{equation*}
so that one can also view this equation as a gradient flow? More generally, is there always such a gradient flow/Morse story associated to a generic perturbed Cauchy-Riemann equation?